# PhpDocumentor Guide links missing

Tags: phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I am trying to create a link from one page in the documentation to another in a `.rst` file:

```
Link to another page :doc:`Another Page`
```

However when I run PHPDocumentor

```
 php phpDocumentor.phar -c .\phpdoc.dist.xml --setting="guides.enabled=true"
```

The HTML generates but I don't get the link included in the page

```
Link to another page
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You link to the path to your document (less the file extension), not the title, so to link to `another-page.rst`, the link is inserted as follows:

```
Link to another page :doc:`another-page`
```